# Removing the optional fields from writing to text field Filehelpers

Tags: c#, option-type, filehelpers

How do I go about removing the optional field from the text field that I have output using the Filehelpers library. I'm using c#

For example,
I have a shared class file
with attributes such as recordnumber, filler, payment, endingspaces

Then I need to write only recordnumber and payment into the text file without the filler.

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.ExactLength)]
public partial class Person
{
[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public string FirstName;
[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public string LastName;

[FieldOptional]
[FieldFixedLength(5)]
public string Optional1;

[FieldOptional]
[FieldFixedLength(5)]
public string Optional2;

[FieldOptional]
[FieldFixedLength(5)]
public string Optional3;
```

}

```
class Program
{
private static void Main(string[] args)
 {
  var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Person>();
  Person[] allPersonRecords = GetPersonExportFromDataBase() as Person[];//This will only get the FirstName,LastName,Optional2. No result for Optional1 and Optional3

  FileHelperEngine enginePerson = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Person));

  enginePerson.AppendToFile(FileName, allPersonRecords ); //Write the records to the file

//Current Output looks like this:John      Lee            title     
//The output which I want is:John      Lee       title

 }
}
```

Comment: Please, include some code for your question.

Comment: Can you detail what you're trying to output as, the source of the data you're outputting etc?

Comment: @Alfergon Hi I have included some code

Comment: @Ceisc Hi, the source of the data I'm trying to output is as shown in the above coding, I want to omit the spaces for empty values for optional 1 and optional 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INotifyWrite` attribute to intercept the line before it is written and modify it. Here is a working example.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public partial class Person : INotifyWrite<Person>
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    [FieldOptional]
    public string Optional1;
    [FieldOptional]
    public string Optional2;
    [FieldOptional]
    public string Optional3;

    public void BeforeWrite(BeforeWriteEventArgs<Person> e)
    {
    }

    public void AfterWrite(AfterWriteEventArgs<Person> e)
    {
        // count the non-optional fields
        var numberOfNonOptionalFields = typeof(Person).GetFields()
            .Where(f => !f.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(a => a is FieldOptionalAttribute))
            .Count();

        // take only the first n tokens
        e.RecordLine = String.Join(",", e.RecordLine.Split(',').Take(numberOfNonOptionalFields));
    }
}      

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Person>();
        var export = engine.WriteString(
                     new Person[] { 
                       new Person() { 
                           FirstName = "Joe", 
                           LastName = "Bloggs", 
                           Optional1 = "Option 1", 
                           Optional2 = "Option 2", 
                           Optional3 = "Option 3" 
                       } 
                     });
        Assert.AreEqual("Joe,Bloggs" + Environment.NewLine, export);
        Console.WriteLine("Export was as expected");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried your codes but I'm not able to perform what I require. Sorry, able to advise me a bit further based on my above codes?

Comment: Then modify `AfterWrite()` to take the just the parts you need: `e.RecordLine = e.RecordLine.Substring(0,20) + e.RecordLine.Substring(25,5)`

Comment: Don't forget `Person` needs to implement `INotifyWrite<Person>` otherwise the `AfterWrite` will never get called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just statically omit the optional fields (i.e. they are *never* used and you *never* want to output them) you could just create another class representing the desired output format and then convert the list from one object type to another using LINQ:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // dummy test data
        var originalAllPersonRecords = new Person[]
        {
            new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Lee", Optional2 = "title" },
        };//This will only get the FirstName,LastName,Optional2. No result for Optional1 and Optional3

        var allPersonRecords = from p in originalAllPersonRecords select new OutputPerson{ FirstName = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName, Optional2 = p.Optional2 };

        FileHelperEngine enginePerson = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(OutputPerson));

        string fileName = "Wherever you want the file to go";
        enginePerson.AppendToFile(fileName, allPersonRecords); //Write the records to the file

        //Current Output looks like this:John      Lee            title     
        //The output which I want is:John      Lee       title
    }
}
//New class added representing the output format
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.ExactLength)]
class OutputPerson
{
    [FieldFixedLength(10)]
    public string FirstName;

    [FieldFixedLength(10)]
    public string LastName;

    [FieldOptional]
    [FieldFixedLength(5)]
    public string Optional2;
}

[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.ExactLength)]
class Person
{
    [FieldFixedLength(10)]
    public string FirstName;
    [FieldFixedLength(10)]
    public string LastName;

    [FieldOptional]
    [FieldFixedLength(5)]
    public string Optional1;

    [FieldOptional]
    [FieldFixedLength(5)]
    public string Optional2;

    [FieldOptional]
    [FieldFixedLength(5)]
    public string Optional3;
}
```